# Large Java Project migrated to Grails - Easiest way to persist?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, persistence

I am currently migrating a relatively large existing java code base into a Grails application. The project consists of many classes with a lot of attributes, including HashMap's.

The grails application should visualize a stepwise process happening in the Java code base and needs therefore persistent access to the Java objects throughout a series of requests.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

I understand that it can be achieved using the Hibernate framework. This would however involve a large amount of extra work by needing to write one configuration file for each class.

I am wondering, if there is an easier alternative, such as another persistence framework implemented in Java which does not require me to write configuration files for each file?

In principle each object could be serialized and stored as a BINARY in the database?

EDIT: a bit of clarification: the process in the Java code is stepwise and interactive, i. e.  the user of the grails app should be able to continue or modify the process/ it's current state by sending requests. this however requires the app to have access to the Java objects of that current state.

Comment: Easy to do by serializing JSON to MongoDB or another document database.  Your model doesn't sound relational to me.

Comment: added some more information to the question. I'm not sure it is possible via json?

Comment: Nothing stateless about this.  How do you plan to make your services idempotent?